# Extract fix columns and one variable column from a list of df´s in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I want to extract the columns 2 and 20 of each df within a list and add a variable for the columns 3:19 and for each of those (16) I want to create a new df.

I tried to build a for loop

```
for i in (3:19){
lapply(abs_bezirke)
y = paste("straftat", i , sep = "")
  assign(y, filter.values <- c(2,i,20))
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Improve your question and this will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not tested

```
sapply(3:19, FUN = function(i, mydata) {
  mydata[, c(2, i, 20)]
}, mydata = mydf, simplify = FALSE)
```

It basically does what your loop is up to, but using sapply. The result should be a list of data.frames.

Comment: hey , thanks but is it possible to apply it to a list df´s aswell?

Comment: Check on `mapply`

Comment: @luis_west care to make another question with a reproducible example that will also have lists and tag me?